# dynamic body with segment shape do not move with a joint

Tags: python, pymunk

In pymunk, I set the body mass and the space gravity, it should automatic fall down, but the body with segment shape do not move, here is my code in pyglet

```
import pyglet
import pymunk
from pymunk.pyglet_util import DrawOptions

window = pyglet.window.Window(1280,720,resizable=False)
options = DrawOptions()

space = pymunk.Space()
space.gravity = 0,-1000

ball_mass = 1
ball_radius = 10

ball_moment = pymunk.moment_for_circle(ball_mass,0,10)
ball = pymunk.Body(ball_mass,ball_moment)
ball_shape = pymunk.Circle(ball,ball_radius)
ball.position =200,500
ball_shape.elasticity = 1
ball_shape.friction = 1

space.add(ball,ball_shape)

stick = pymunk.Body(1,100,body_type=pymunk.Body.DYNAMIC)
stick_shape = pymunk.Segment(stick,(0,0),(150,150),4)
stick.position = (300,400)
pin = pymunk.PivotJoint(space.static_body,stick,(300,400))
# stick.apply_impulse_at_local_point((0,-100),(150,150))
space.add(stick,stick_shape,pin)


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    space.debug_draw(options)

def update(dt):
    space.step(dt)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1/60.0)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

the ball fall down but the stick do not move, or apply_impulse_at_local_point on stick, I just wondering, if there is no PivotJoint, the stick fall down, I just pin one point of the stick, why it does not move, it should rotate, is it?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the stick has its center of gravity at one end. That make it behave a bit strange. Try making it have its center of gravity in its actual center instead.

```
stick_shape = pymunk.Segment(stick,(-75,-75),(75,75),4)
```